# .net assembly custom attribute injection

Tags: c#, build, .net-assembly

I've got a c# desktop project and CI server which builds that project after each git push.

I want somehow to inject custom attrubute (git commint hash) in each generated assembly after build, for better version control and support in production (i need to know thich exactly version was used when some problems was issued).

How can i do that?

Comment: Why not do it before build? You could auto-populate `[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("blah")]` in `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

Comment: Hmm. very interesting. Good idea. Thank you.